# How to load and use a lib.a file in an android project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am trying to use nng library in my android project

I have built a library "libnng.a" using the guide [here](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng/blob/master/docs/BUILD_ANDROID.adoc).

But when I am trying to load this .a file into the android project, I am getting the following error.

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libnng.so" not found**

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project("nativecpptest")
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        nativecpptest

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp)

add_library( nng STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( nng
        PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libnng.a)

include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        nativecpptest
        nng
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

MainActivity.java

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativecpptest");
        System.loadLibrary("nng");
    }
```

Can someone help me in fixing this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for `System.loadLibrary("nng");`. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Yes, the issue is gone once removed that line. But how can we be sure that the library is loaded ?

Comment: Because you linked it statically to `libnativecpptest`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. But now I am getting the following error : libnng.a: error adding symbols: File in the wrong format

Comment: You must have one `libnng.a` per ABI you are compiling for. (and link to the correct one)